# How can I give time varying temperature dependent heat source term in COMSOL Multiphysics?

Tags: comsol

The conditions are as follows:
`0<t<0.1 sec`,   Q= Q_1 W/m^3
`0.1<t<2.1 sec`, Q= 0 W/m^3
`2.1<t<2.2 sec`, Q= Q_2 W/m^3
`2.2<t<4.2 sec`, Q= 0 W/m^3
Where, both Q_1 and Q_2 are a function of temperature, which I have already defined in Global Definitions.

Comment: Are Q_1 and Q_2 time varying or constants?  If they are time varying, is it convenient enough to use a single function to represent the entire heat profile over time?

Comment: Dear sir, Q_1 and Q_2 are only the functions of temperature.

Comment: So Q_1 and Q_2 change value as time passes?